# Request parameters not saving on model_params on n:n relationship with check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, request, many-to-many

I am using `Rails 5.1` and im having some issues saving params on an `n:n` relationship.

I have three models:

```
class Course < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :studio
has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy
has_many :has_category
has_many :categories, through: :has_category
validates :name, presence: true
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
has_many :has_category
has_many :courses, through: :has_category
end

class HasCategory < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :course
end
```

and a simple form to create a new course with different categories using check_box_tag (not sure if using it correctly though)

```
<%= simple_form_for [@studio, @course] do |f| %>
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :description %>

<% @categories.each do |category| %>
<%= check_box_tag "course[category_ids][]", category.id, true %>
<%= category.name%>
<% end %>

<%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```

And all is permitted and created on the courses controller:

```
def new
@studio = Studio.find(params[:studio_id])
@course = Course.new
@course.studio = @studio
@categories = Category.all
end

def create
@studio = Studio.find(params[:studio_id])
@course = Course.new(course_params)
@course.studio = @studio
@categories = params[:category_ids]

if @course.save
  redirect_to course_path(@course)
else
  render :new
end
end      

def course_params
  params.require(:course).permit(:studio_id, :name, :description, :category_ids)
  end
```

With better_errors i know the categories are being requested, here the request info:

```
"course"=>{"name"=>"Course test", "description"=>"testing", "category_ids"=>["2", "3"]}, "commit"=>"Create Course", "controller"=>"courses", "action"=>"create", "studio_id"=>"16"}
```

but the categories are not saved on course_params, HasCategory instance or on the Course, i´ve tried with @course.categories = params[:category_ids] and other solutions without success.

How do i save the categories to the courses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

Change the strong parameter with `category_ids: []`

```
def course_params
    params.require(:course).permit(:studio_id, :name, :description, category_ids: [])
end
```

Comment out this line `@categories = params[:category_ids]`

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! it helps, but categories are now saving twice (ex: "[arts, arts, sports, sports]" why could that be???